# LINQ to Entities LEFT JOIN single aggregate result

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

Low priority question as I already have a solution in place, but I think there is a better way. I am trying to return a single result just like this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) IsAuthenticated, COUNT(UTP.HashedPassword) IsTempPassword
FROM [EnterpriseDB].[dbo].[UniversalCurrentPassword] AS UCP
LEFT JOIN [EnterpriseDB].[dbo].[UniversalTempPassword] AS UTP
ON UCP.UniversalId = UTP.UniversalId
WHERE UCP.UniversalId = 00000
      AND (UCP.HashedPassword = 'some_password'
           OR UTP.HashedPassword = 'some_password')
```

Here is what I have already:

```cs
//returns null if mismatch 
//returns true if temp password
//returns false if current password
bool? query = 
    (from Password in context.UniversalCurrentPasswords
     join TempPassword in context.UniversalTempPasswords
     on Password.UniversalId equals TempPassword.UniversalId
     where Password.UniversalId == longId
     && (Password.HashedPassword == pwd
         || Password.UniversalMaster.UniversalTempPassword.HashedPassword == pwd)
     select (TempPassword.HashedPassword == null ? true : false)).FirstOrDefault();
```

what do you think - is there a better way?

Comment: The type of the conditional expression in your select clause is bool, not bool?, and the default for bool is false, so if you have no records, the `query` variable will be false; it can never be null.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bool? query =   
     (from Password in context.UniversalCurrentPasswords 
      join TempPassword in context.UniversalTempPasswords 
      on Password.UniversalId equals TempPassword.UniversalId into tp
      from TempPassword in tp.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where Password.UniversalId == longId 
          && (Password.HashedPassword == pwd 
          || Password.UniversalMaster.UniversalTempPassword.HashedPassword == pwd) 
      select (TempPassword == null ? null as bool? : 
              TempPassword.HashedPassword == null ? (bool?)true : (bool?)false)
     ).FirstOrDefault();
```